# Sessions in zend are not saved. Wrong config?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I try to build a simple refresh counter in the zend framework with zend_session_namespace, but it is not working as expected. I can't call the namespace after it is set. In the examble below the code shows "1" again and again. Any advise for troubleshooting?

```
Zend_Session::start();
$defaultNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('numbertester');

// Increment page views
if(isset($defaultNamespace->number)){
    // The code is never entering here
    $defaultNamespace->number++;
} else {
    $defaultNamespace->number = 1;
}

echo $defaultNamespace->number;
```

**UPDATE**

I found this script to test the session config. When I run it on the server it end up in the last part and tells me, that my session config it incorrect. I am not sure what to do from here?

```
if( function_exists('ini_get') &&
    in_array(strtolower(ini_get('session.save_handler')), array('user', 'users')) ) {
  if( function_exists('ini_set') &&
      false !== ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files') &&
      false !== ini_set('session.save_path', APPLICATION_PATH . '/temporary/session/') ) {
    if( !is_writable(APPLICATION_PATH . '/temporary/session/') ) {
      throw new Exception('Please set full permissions on temporary/session (chmod 0777).');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception('Your session configuration is incorrect and ' .
        'could not be automatically corrected. Please set ' .
        'session.save_handler=files and session.save_path=/tmp (or your ' .
        'temporary directory on non-Linux OSes.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be your problem is somewhere else because I tested the code and its working on my side. For details please review this :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

Comment: @kj The session basics, do not seem to give any troubleshooting help, when the code fails. Could use som input on why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution(if you working on local machine) in your php.ini file:

Define path to save sessions

```
session.save_path = "C:\php\sessiondata\"
```

Whether to use cookies.

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```

To Initialize session on request startup.

```
Set session.auto_start = 1
```

Name of the session (used as cookie name).

```
session.name = PHPSESSID
```

Comment: according to http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html 
doing session.auto_start = 1
is wrong.